# Refactor this code into something modular

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code

```
addSelectorLabel = (params) => {
  let valEntidad = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "type") return tipo })?.value || ""
  let valCNAE = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "cnae") return tipo })?.value || ""
  let valProvince = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "province") return tipo })?.value || ""
  let valVia = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "address_prefix") return tipo })?.value || ""

  if (valEntidad !== "") {
    let labelSelector = EntidadArr.find(tipo => {
      if (tipo.cod === valEntidad) {
        return tipo
      }
    })?.val || ""

    if (labelSelector !== "") {
      params.push(
        {
          name: "typeLabel", value: labelSelector, hasError: false
        }
      )
    }
  }

  if (valCNAE !== "") {
    let labelSelector = CNAE.find(tipo => {
      if (tipo.cod === valCNAE) {
        return tipo
      }
    })?.val || ""
    if (labelSelector !== "") {
      params.push(
        {
          name: "cnaeLabel", value: labelSelector, hasError: false
        }
      )
    }
  }

  if (valProvince !== "") {
    let labelSelector = ProvinciaArr.find(tipo => {
      if (tipo.cod === valProvince) {
        return tipo
      }
    })?.val || ""
    if (labelSelector !== "") {
      params.push(
        {
          name: "provinceLabel", value: labelSelector, hasError: false
        }
      )
    }
  }

  if (valVia !== "") {
    let labelSelector = ViaArr.find(tipo => {
      if (tipo.cod === valVia) {
        return tipo
      }
    })?.val || ""
    if (labelSelector !== "") {
      params.push(
        {
          name: "viaLabel", value: labelSelector, hasError: false
        }
      )
    }
  }


  return params
}
```

The same process is repeated 4 times, so im trying to create a modular function to make it shorter.
But im not really sure where to start

Im looking to create something like for the if sentences

```
export const selectLabel = async (jsonToCrawl, valueToFind, params) => {
  let labelSelector = jsonToCrawl.find(tipo => {
    if (tipo.cod === valueToFind) {
      return tipo
    }
  })?.val || ""

  if (labelSelector !== "") {
    params.push(
      {
        name: "typeLabel", value: labelSelector, hasError: false
      }
    )
    return params
  }
}

//call it like -->       params = selectLabel(EntidadArr , valEntidad, params)
```

But im wondering. what happens with the params.push ? Do i have to return it? and reset params?
Im not sure how to apprach this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing something like this, what you want to look for is what changes in the different copies of the code. Then you make a function that accepts the things that change as parameters, and uses those parameter values to do the work. This called *parameterizing* the code.

For instance, let's look just at the initial part:

```
let valEntidad = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "type") return tipo })?.value || ""
let valCNAE = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "cnae") return tipo })?.value || ""
let valProvince = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "province") return tipo })?.value || ""
let valVia = params.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === "address_prefix") return tipo })?.value || ""
```

All four `find` calls above do the same thing, the only thing that varies is the `name` that the code checks against.

That means you can write a function accepting that name and have it do the work:

```
function findTypeValueByName(types, name) {
    return types.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === name) return tipo })?.value || "";
}
```

Then you use that function:

```
let valEntidad = findTypeValueByName(params, "type");
let valCNAE = findTypeValueByName(params, "cnae");
let valProvince = findTypeValueByName(params, "province");
let valVia = findTypeValueByName(params, "address_prefix");
```

You can apply the same process to the four `if` statements. They have more things that vary, so there will be more than one parameter to use, but the same approach will work for them as well.

---

Side note: The callback for `find` is supposed to return a flag (true/false) for whether the entry is the one you want. So instead of:

```
function findTypeValueByName(types, name) {
    return types.find(tipo => { if (tipo.name === name) return tipo })?.value || "";
}
```

just return the result of the comparison:

```
function findTypeValueByName(types, name) {
    return types.find(tipo => tipo.name === name)?.value || "";
}
```

That does the same thing. Your original code does work, but the reason it works is a by-product of the fact that your callback wasn't returning anything (so implicitly returns `undefined`) in the false case, and was returning an object in the true case. That happens to work, but it's best to clearly return a flag instead.